# xsl unique value key for all nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I use this xsl file to transform from xml to rdf. And give the position as a resource name "rdf:about="

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/schema/"
xml:lang="en-US">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<!-- file -->
    <xsl:for-each select="file">
          <xsl:element name="ns:file">
            <xsl:attribute name="rdf:about">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>  
            </xsl:attribute>
<!-- paragraph -->
            <xsl:element name="ns:Paragraph">   
                <xsl:for-each select="paragraph">
                      <xsl:element name="ns:paragraph">
                        <xsl:attribute name="rdf:about">
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])"/>  
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
<!-- phrase -->
                <xsl:element name="ns:Phrase">  
                    <xsl:for-each select="phrase">
                             <xsl:element name="ns:phrase">
                            <xsl:attribute name="rdf:about">
                                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])"/>  
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element>
<!-- word -->
                    <xsl:element name="ns:Word">    
                        <xsl:for-each select="word">
                                <xsl:element name="ns:word">
                                <xsl:attribute name="rdf:about">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])"/>  
                                </xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On this xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<file>
  <paragraph>
    <phrase>
        <word>
    </phrase>
  </paragraph>
  <paragraph>
    <phrase>
        <word/>
        <word/>
    </phrase>
    <phrase>
        <word/>
    </phrase>
  </paragraph>
</file>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:file xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/schema/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" rdf:about="">
<ns:Paragraph>
<ns:paragraph rdf:about="0"/>
<ns:Phrase>
<ns:phrase rdf:about="0"/>
<ns:Word>
<ns:word rdf:about="0"/>
</ns:Word>
</ns:Phrase>
<ns:paragraph rdf:about="1"/>
<ns:Phrase>
<ns:phrase rdf:about="0"/>
<ns:Word>
<ns:word rdf:about="0"/>
<ns:word rdf:about="1"/>
</ns:Word>
<ns:phrase rdf:about="1"/>
<ns:Word>
<ns:word rdf:about="0"/>
</ns:Word>
</ns:Phrase>
</ns:Paragraph>
</ns:file>
```

I need to have a unique resource name. for each resource so i get?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:file xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/schema/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" rdf:about="">
<ns:Paragraph>
<ns:paragraph rdf:about="0"/>
<ns:Phrase>
<ns:phrase rdf:about="0"/>
<ns:Word>
<ns:word rdf:about="0"/>
</ns:Word>
</ns:Phrase>
<ns:paragraph rdf:about="1"/>
<ns:Phrase>
<ns:phrase rdf:about="1"/>
<ns:Word>
<ns:word rdf:about="1"/>
<ns:word rdf:about="2"/>
</ns:Word>
<ns:phrase rdf:about="1"/>
<ns:Word>
<ns:word rdf:about="3"/>
</ns:Word>
</ns:Phrase>
</ns:Paragraph>
</ns:file>
```

How can i do this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution would be to change `preceding-sibling::` to `preceding::`.

Alternatively, you could  use `xsl:number` or - if all you're interested in is getting a unique id, not necessarily consecutive - use the `generate-id()` function.

---

P.S. Your styleheet is horribly and unnecessarily complex. For example, instead of:

```
<xsl:element name="ns:file">
```

you can write simply:

```
<ns:file>
```

You should also learn to use the [*attribute value template*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates), and consider re-using a single template recursively for all your element types.

Comment: Worked.The schema is very complex, i put just a part of it. The "file", "paragraph" ... here are elements and they get attribute values but i didn't mention them in the example. I'm writing my thesis and i had to make a test fast. I will surely learn xsl later.  Thank you very much.